# Non-greedy regex not working like I would like (Notepad++ 8.1.1)

Tags: regex, notepad++, non-greedy

I am using Noteapd++ v8.1.1 on Windows 10 to edit a save file from the game Rimworld in order to change the position of items on the map.

For example, I want to move all the "Building" and "Building_*something*" (and not the other *thing*s) from y=104 to y=103 in a list of different items (here, the coordinates are in the form (x, 0, y), I simplified the code a bit and added line numbers):

```
58  <thing Class="Plant">
59      <def>Plant_TreeOak</def>
60      <id>Plant_TreeOak41339</id>
61      <pos>(100, 0, 105)</pos>
62   </thing>
63   <thing Class="Building">
64      <def>Wall</def>
65      <id>Wall28005</id>  
66      <pos>(101, 0, 105)</pos>
68   </thing>
69   <thing Class="Building">
70      <def>Wall</def>
71      <id>Wall29667</id>
72      <pos>(103, 0, 105)</pos>
74   </thing>
75   <thing Class="Building">
76      <def>Wall</def>
77      <id>Wall28005</id>
78      <pos>(101, 0, 104)</pos>
80   </thing>
81   <thing Class="Building_Door">
82      <def>Door</def>
83      <id>Door642106</id>
84      <pos>(102, 0, 104)</pos>
86   </thing>
87   <thing Class="Building">
88      <def>Wall</def>
89      <id>Wall29667</id>
90      <pos>(103, 0, 104)</pos>
92   </thing>
93   <thing Class="Plant">
94      <def>Plant_Grass</def>
95      <id>Plant_Grass203219</id>
96      <pos>(104, 0, 104)</pos>
97   </thing>
```

(here, on y=105 we have an oak, a wall, nothing, a wall; and on y=104 we have a wall, a door, a wall, grass).

I try to find `<thing Class="Building(.*?)104\)` (singleline) and replace it with `<thing Class="Building$1103\)`.
For this example, the first match starts from line 69 and ends line 78, while I'd like it to start at line 75 (the two next matches work fine).

I tried many things and looked for accurate documentation to no avail (I can't even find what regex engine Notepad++ is using...).
Actually, I think that I don't understand fully how "non-greedy" regexes work.

Please consider that English is not my mother language, so technical English is sometimes tricky for me.

Thanks for your help, and please remember that I am using Notepad++, that handles regexes a bit differently sometimes (e.g. here, the `\)` in the replace line to make a `)`).

Comment: NPP uses Boost regex library.

Comment: Use `<thing Class="Building(?:_[^"]*)?">(?:\R.*){2}\R.*\(.*,\h*\K104(?=\))` and replace with `103`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Cl0Kv/1).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, your regex also matches the x (horizontal) 104 in line 96 (104, 0, 104).
@user2864740 : it doesn't seem to work written like this, but I'm looking into that "?!" negative lookahead thingy, thanks.

Comment: It does not match anything on Line 96. The `thing` has `Class="Plant"`  there, so there is no match. My regex only matches on lines 78, 84 and 90, please make sure you are using my regex.

Comment: See my answer with the right settings.

Comment: Sorry, I was fooled by the syntax highlighting in NPP. '-_-
It seems to work, thanks, now I have to try to understand how to adapt it to my other needs...

Comment: See my explanation. Also, I assumed the structure of the document is fixed and you always have `def`, `id` and `pos` tags inside each `thing`. Else, you'd need another fix. Something like [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/9Cl0Kv/2). If you need help with adaptation, please add the real test case to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `<thing Class="Building` and then match two lines below, than grab all before the last number before a `)`:

```js
<thing Class="Building(?:_[^"]*)?">(?:\R.*){2}\R.*\(.*,\h*\K104(?=\))
```

Replace with `103`. See the [regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/9Cl0Kv/1/)

*Details*:

- `<thing Class="Building` - a fixed string
- `(?:_[^"]*)?` - an optional seqence of a `_` char followed with zero or more chars other than a `"` char
- `">` - a fixed string
- `(?:\R.*){2}` - two lines
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `.*` - 0+ chars other than line brea chars as many as possble
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `.*` - 0+ chars other than line brea chars as many as possble
- `,\h*` - a comma and 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `104` -  a fixed value
- `(?=\))` - next char must be a `)`.

[image]

Comment: Just a question: I have to tick "PCRE (PHP <7.3)" when I use regex101 for NPP?

Comment: @oli_vi_er Both options will do, you are not going to need any specific PCRE only regex features here.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is being lazy. At the *given* starting location, that was the smallest valid match.

Instead, use the following:

```
<thing Class="Building(?:(?!<thing).)*?104\)
```

The `(?!..)` is a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which is supported per the [boost syntax here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/regex/doc/syntax.html). I also verified it NPP with the give data ;-)

An expanded explanation of the regex can be generated at https://www.mobzystems.com/online/explain-regular-expression/.

Comment: I have fixed the tempered greedy token syntax, `.` must aways be placed  after the lookahead

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the update. However, both approaches appear to return the same matches locally - I wonder in what context(s) it would result in different matches.

Comment: When the right-hand part follows the left-hand one immediately. It is a very rare case, and probably will never be a problem here, but a TGT must be written correctly.